# Regular expression for valid boolean expression

Tags: regex, boolean, expression, formula

I want to search for valid boolean formulae e.g A'+BC(D+E) among a list of formulae. Any help on a regular expression to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such regex.  Boolean expressions can have arbitrary levels of nested parentheses, which makes them a non-regular language.

Comment: If we drop the requirement for having brackets, e.g A'+BC, then I presume it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it using python using some independant rules, for example:

- checking that the expression does not have 'and' followed by 'or', nor 'or' followed by 'and'
- open parenthesis '(' must be followed by something other than 'and', 'or' ; and it must follows 'and' or 'or' (except when figuring at the beginning)
- closing parenthesis ')' must be followed by 'and' or 'or' or string-end character '$' and it must follow something other than 'or','and'
- .....

This is an example using python (but assuming that we use PCRE regexp to support variable width look-behind):

```
    tmp= query
    tmp= re.sub("[(]", " (", query)
    tmp= re.sub(" +", " ", query)
    if re.search(r"\(( *and| *or| *\))", tmp) or re.search(r"(?<!\band|\bor) \(", tmp):
        return False

    if re.search(r"\)(?!( *or\b| *and\b|$))", tmp) or re.search(r"(\band *|\bor *)\)", tmp):
        return False

    if re.search(r"(\band|\bor)( and\b| or\b)", tmp) or re.search(r"(?<!\band|\bor) (?!and\b|or\b)", tmp):
        return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964989/6607562). But I have developed a regex which can detect logical expression with single level parenthesis in python. I have used this [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library.

```
    import regex

    filter = "(abc < 23 or def ==0) or cr<0.5 or (cde_1 > 2.3 or ghe >=2.4 or afg==3)"

    metric = "(?P<metric>\w+)"
    number = "(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
    operator = "(?:==|<=|>=|>|<)"
    exp = "metric\s*operator\s*number(?:\s+(?:and|or)\s+metric\s*operator\s*number)*".replace("metric", metric).replace("number",number).replace("operator",operator)

    final_exp = "^(?:exp|\(exp\))(?:\s+(?:and|or)\s+(?:exp|\(exp\)))*$".replace("exp", exp)

    m = regex.match(r"{0}".format(final_exp), filter)
```