# C# Validate string if it's linq expression with NugGet Library

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The string linq query can be entered dynamically, not only by developer.
And it should be validated.

Do you have a regex expression or nuget to check if a string is a valid linq expression?

For example for a valid string linq expression :

```
(a.AccountId== 33
|| a.AccountId == 2
|| a.AccountId == 15) &&
(a.RoleId == 1||  a.RoleId == 3||  a.RoleId == 4)
```

- Note - It can be also: (It can be each time a different linq query)

```
(a.TransactionId == 5 && a.EmployeeName == "Tony") || etc..
```

Example for string that can't be parsed:

```
(a.AccountId== 33
|| a.AccountId == 2
|| a.AccountId == 15)
(a.a.RoleId == 1||  a.RoleId == 3||  a.RoleId == 4)
```

Between those 2 , There is no Operator and you can see the a.a.
which is invalid and can't be parsed to linq.

```
15)
(a.a.RoleId == 1||
```

If someone knows a good C# NuGet like ExpressionEvaluator for .net framework 4.5, Please let me know.

I have used ExpressionEvaluator, Dot net framework 4.5, But it says that this is a valid linq but it's not:

```
(a.AccountId== 33
|| a.AccountId == 2
|| a.AccountId == 15)
(a.a.RoleId == 1||  a.RoleId == 3||  a.RoleId == 4)
```

success is true, but it should be false.

```
success = new CompiledExpression(query);
```

- Result of a NuGet or Regex

Inside the textbox, Will return Valid:

```
"(a.ProfileId == 5 && a.ProfileName == 'Alex')"
```

Invalid: - l.l double l.l is invalid

```
"l.l.LinkId == 5 || l.LinkName == 'Alex'"
```

valid and string can be parsed

```
"l.LinkId == 5 || l.LinkName == 'Alex'"
```

The parameter l. or a. can be changed to any A-Z
I have tried to use DynamicExpresso.Core but i need to specify the parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for valid boolean expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964977/regular-expression-for-valid-boolean-expression)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Dynamic Express library, created a dynamic class with
property name and property class, passed the right x => arrow function parameter
and my query and they dynamic class and it worked.
Solved with:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicExpresso.Core/

Answer (score -1):

If I understand it correctly you are searching for a LINQ query that uses the "IN" keyword (SQL). Instead, you can use Contains in LINQ.

**.NET:**

```
List<int> number = new List<int>{33,2,15};
from p in a
where p.AccountId.Contains(number)
select p
```

Comment: I need to validated the linq with regex.

Comment: it's a string that is entered by some one else, you don't know if it;s AccountId or RoleId or ImageId, or TransactionId